# Unique reference numbers

Tags: workflow, custom-list, counter

I am using SharePoint as an incident reporting system.  Users will submit an incident report (list form) that populates a list.  Each incident needs to have a unique ID number, which I can easily do by  creating a ID column that runs a counter.  The problem is, after an incident is submitted, I need to workflow it to a secondary list (that the original user who submitted the incident will not have access to) and as the incident is moved from one list to another it needs to retain the original unique ID number.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share Point Lists already have a unique ID generated for them (The column is called ID). All you have to do is add this ID to the second list via the workflow.

You can either have a look up column in List B that is pointed to List A or just have a normal column (text or number).

In this case I would use a look up column as it provides more features in the long run as well as a handy link to that users can click on to look at the original List A item.